# Formatting warning in F#

Tags: f#, formatting

The following code triggers a formatting warning on each `let` ("possible incorrect indentation"):

```
module UtilTests =
    [<Test>] let simpleWithNth ()= true |> should be True
    [<Test>] let negIndex () = true |> should be True
    [<Test>] let tooBigIndex () = true |> should be True
    [<Test>] let lastIndex () = true |> should be True
```

The following does not:

```
module UtilTests =
    [<Test>] let simpleWithNth ()= true |> should be True
     [<Test>] let negIndex () = true |> should be True
      [<Test>] let tooBigIndex () = true |> should be True
       [<Test>] let lastIndex () = true |> should be True
```

Why does it want each `let` to be more indented than the one above it? (Is there some way to have Visual Studio 2012 auto-format?)

Comment: I think this is a bug, as uour original code should be valid

Comment: Put the attribute on the line above the let.

Comment: @Brian - whilst this fixes the warning many of the doc examples have the attribute on the same line - the Attributes examples for field and property have the attributes on the same line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Brian said in the comment, the usual way of applying attributes to a `let` function is to write the attribute on the line before the `let` binding. I would also expect the code you wrote to work, because the body of the function is on the same line, but apparently, the compiler does not think so....

However, there is another way to apply attributes to `let` functions that works well in your example:

```
module UtilTests = 
  let [<Test>] simpleWithNth ()= true |> should be True 
  let [<Test>] negIndex () = true |> should be True 
  let [<Test>] tooBigIndex () = true |> should be True 
  let [<Test>] lastIndex () = true |> should be True
```

This style is needed if you're writing recursive functions - then attributes on previous lines do not work and you need to write `let rec [<Foo>] foo () = ... and [<Bar>] bar () = ...`.